# Plotting data with Multiple Conditions on a Single Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to make a plot using ggplot2 with side by side bars generated from certain conditions that can be calculated from the data.  I suspect the problem is formatting my data properly so that ggplot will give me what I want.  I can't for the life of me get it right though.

What I have is data frame filled with rows for each time a student takes a course at a school.  The variables of interest are Student.ID, Course.ID, Session, Fiscal.Year, and Facility.  Each row is an occurrence of a student taking a course and tells what course they took, where they took it, etc.  As far as I know, this is what's required for the data to be in long form (correct me if I'm wrong).  The only field with possible NA values is the Facility, but I plan to exclude those from the plot anyways so you can treat the data frame as being completely filled.

What I want to do is produce a plot showing by fiscal year how many courses had <= 2 students, how many had < 4 students, and how many had <= 4 students, and how many courses were offered total.  *(Note: When I'm talking about how many courses were offered, I'm taking into account that each course may be offered multiple times and each time it's offered it has a session number associated with it.  The tricky part is that the session numbers are not unique.  I hope that makes sense, and I can try to clarify more if needed.)*

I envision the final product being multiple charts using facet on the locations, x-axis being Fiscal.Year, and the y-axis being the number of courses/sessions.  For each FY in the chart, I want different colored bars stacked side by side showing the numbers of <2, <4, <=4, total courses offered for that FY at that location.  Consider the following chart, only instead of "Income, Expense, Loans", I want "<=2, <4, <=4, Total" (they would also be ascending from left to right, since there is inclusion between the different categories).

[image: Sample chart similar to what I'm looking for]

Here is some sample data to work with (typed as CSV since I can't just copy the head of the file).  I've excluded the Facility column because faceting by that is easy and we can just assume one FY for a test example I think.  For reference, it should have 3 courses with <=2 students, 5 courses with < 4, and 6 with <= 4.  The total number of courses offered in this sample set is 6.

`ID,CourseID,Session,Fiscal.Year
101,1,,1,FY13
102,1,1,FY13
103,1,1,FY13
104,1,1,FY13
101,2,1,FY13
102,2,1,FY13
103,2,1,FY13
101,2,2,FY13
102,2,2,FY13
103,2,2,FY13
101,3,1,FY13
102,3,1,FY13
101,3,2,FY13
102,3,2,FY13
101,3,3,FY13
102,3,3,FY13`

I have tried:

- Creating a new data frame using ddply with columns Course.ID, Session, FY, Facility, Count of Students.  Then I used created a new column called "TwoLess", which just has a 1 if the count is <=2 and 0 otherwise.  (I repeated this process for the other conditions, creating new columns for the others as well similarly.)  Using the ggplot code below I was able to get a faceted plot for only one of the conditions (ie: only <=2 students), but wasn't able to get them to combine.  I believe the following is the equivalent code used, changed to reflect my test set above:

`ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(y = TwoLess, x = Fiscal.Year)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + facet_wrap(~Facility)`

I am thinking this approach is heavily flawed and I'm missing out on some of the "niceness" of having data in long form, since that's what ggplot wants as I understand it.

What is the best way to approach plotting this in ggplot?

It's also worth mentioning that while I have access to some of the more popular packages like ggplot2, plyr, reshape2, I do not have the ability to load all packages so I would prefer a solution that uses the above packages (or any of their dependencies).  It shouldn't be that large of a restriction, I don't think.

Comment: Could you provide some real data or something closer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this help?

Extending your data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 
102L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 102L, 101L, 102L), CourseID = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Session = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Fiscal.Year = c("FY13", "FY13", 
    "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", 
    "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY13", "FY14", "FY14", 
    "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", 
    "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY14", "FY15", "FY15", 
    "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", 
    "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15", "FY15")), .Names = c("ID", 
"CourseID", "Session", "Fiscal.Year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))

df
    ID CourseID Session Fiscal.Year
1  101        1       1        FY13
2  102        1       1        FY13
3  103        1       1        FY13
4  104        1       1        FY13
5  101        2       1        FY13
6  102        2       1        FY13
7  103        2       1        FY13
8  101        2       2        FY13
9  102        2       2        FY13
10 103        2       2        FY13
11 101        3       1        FY13
12 102        3       1        FY13
13 101        3       2        FY13
14 102        3       2        FY13
15 101        3       3        FY13
16 102        3       3        FY13
17 101        1       1        FY14
18 102        1       1        FY14
19 103        1       1        FY14
20 104        1       1        FY14
21 101        2       1        FY14
22 102        2       1        FY14
23 103        2       1        FY14
24 101        2       2        FY14
25 102        2       2        FY14
26 103        2       2        FY14
27 101        3       1        FY14
28 102        3       1        FY14
29 101        3       2        FY14
30 102        3       2        FY14
31 101        3       3        FY14
32 102        3       3        FY14
33 101        1       1        FY15
34 102        1       1        FY15
35 103        1       1        FY15
36 104        1       1        FY15
37 101        2       1        FY15
38 102        2       1        FY15
39 103        2       1        FY15
40 101        2       2        FY15
41 102        2       2        FY15
42 103        2       2        FY15
43 101        3       1        FY15
44 102        3       1        FY15
45 101        3       2        FY15
46 102        3       2        FY15
47 101        3       3        FY15
48 102        3       3        FY15
```

Summarise it with dplyr

```
d1 <- df %>%
  group_by(CourseID, Session, Fiscal.Year) %>%
  summarise(n=length(ID))
```

And again

```
d2 <- d1 %>%
  group_by(Fiscal.Year) %>%
  summarise(d1 = length(n[n <= 2]),
            d2 = length(n[n <  4]),
            d3 = length(n[n <= 4])
  )
library(reshape2)
d3 <- melt(d2)
ggplot(d3, aes(Fiscal.Year, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

to plot it with ggplot2

[image: barplot]

Someone must provide a clever option. I'm tired. Go to bed now.

Comment: `summarise(n=length(ID))` can be `summarise(n = n())`.

Comment: @jazzurro true! but for me the idiom is not the most pedagogical.

Comment: This looks very much like what I want!  I will have to test it at work when I return, but I hadn't thought to use plyr twice then melt the results back into a data frame.  Also, is %>% supposed to be %.%?  If not, what the heck does %>% do?  Either way, this solves a problem I haven't been able to figure out for the past week, so thank you!  I'll test it and accept once everything checks out.

Comment: @KyleSykes Yes, %>% is supposed to be %.%. Same behavior. The idiom of dplyr accepts the use of pipes like %>%.

Comment: @KyleSykes did you got it working and managed to facet the final plot?

Comment: @PauloCardoso I won't be able to test until tomorrow morning.  I will report back then!

Comment: @PauloCardoso It worked perfectly and faceted just fine.  The only major change I made to the above code was adding `d4 = length(n)` to the second ddply call to count the total number of courses offered.  Everything else seems to align with what I've calculated before, so thank you for helping me solve a problem that's been bugging me for 2 weeks now!